# Why does the sigma algebra generated by a rectangle include one side of a number line?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Consider an open interval $(-\infty, a)$, where $a \in \mathbb{Q}$. Why does it hold that

$$
\left\{ (-\infty, a) \mid a \in \mathbb{Q} \right\} \subset \sigma \left( \{ [x,y) \mid x,y, \in \mathbb{Q} \} \right)
$$

I know that you can write $(-\infty, a)$ as $ \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [-n, a) $ but I struggle to see how that is an element of the sigma algebra generated by some rational interval $[x, y)$. I'm assuming that you cannot just simply set $x = -n$ since $x$ is fixed.

Comment: Because you can write the left hand side as a countable union of elements of the right hand side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* simply set $x=-n$.  The notation $$\{ [x,y) \mid x,y, \in \mathbb{Q} \}$$ means the set whose elements are $[x,y)$ where $x$ and $y$ range over *all* elements of $\mathbb{Q}$, not just some fixed elements.  So the $\sigma$-algebra generated by this set contains the interval $[x,y)$ for *all* $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$.  In particular, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we can set $x=-n$ and $y=a$ to conclude that $[-n,a)$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: $[-n,a)$ is also in the set $[x,y)$ as well then (without the sigma algebra generator), correct? I always thought that when using things like $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ it means for some fixed $x$, and when you want to specify any $x$, you use the $\forall$ symbol.

Comment: $[-n,a)$ is an element of the set $\{ [x,y) \mid x,y, \in \mathbb{Q} \}$, if that's what you mean (note that $\{ [x,y) \mid x,y, \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ is a very different set from $[x,y)$).  You can think of this notation as analogous to summation notation.  When we write $\sum_{x\in A}f(x)$, we are summing up the values $f(x)$ for all the different elements $x\in A$.  Similarly, here we are forming a set whose elements are $[x,y)$ for all the different $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$.